# Hide controls on the NewForm.aspx

Tags: javascript, jquery

The `newForm.aspx` page of the SharePoint Calendar has a radio button for **"No end date"**. I am trying to use the function below to hide the radio button. Is the title of the radio button the display name i.e. **"No end date"**?

```
//this gets the field based on title identifier and tagname
function getTagFromIdentifierAndTitle(tagName, identifier, title) {
 var len = identifier.length;
var tags = document.getElementsByTagName(tagName);
 for (var i=0; i < tags.length; i++) {
var tempString = tags[i].id;
if (tags[i].title == title && (identifier == "" || tempString.indexOf(identifier) ==   tempString.length - len)) {
 return tags[i];
}
}
return null;
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

I resolved the issue by inserting the following code in the NewForm.aspx:

Now the radio button for "No end date is hidden $('nobr:contains("No end date")').closest('tr').hide();